# What's the meaning of would in the following sentences

Tags: sentence-meaning, modal-verbs

I know the meaning of "would" when it is used in conditional sentences, but I have a huge problem when I'd like to use it without "if". I read lots of websites and similar posts here but I cannot understand it. It would be a great help for me if you could help me. I write a few such sentences in the following. Thank you in advance!

> He says it **would** then be too late to throw the changes into reverse.
> The Sun (2008)

> The company says that such a deal **would** allow work to start immediately.
> Times, Sunday Times (2017)

> The study from the Tony Blair Institute for Global Change says that limitations on flying **would** need people to cut their travels by plane by 6% by 2035.

Answer (score 1):

Your example *is* conditional, it just uses something previously mentioned as the condition.

Your example says:

> The company says that **such a deal would** allow work to start immediately.

The 'deal' referred to must have been previously mentioned. It is saying that **if** that deal were in place, then work could start.

Broadly speaking, we use "would" to indicate possibility, rather than "will", which indicates certainty. For example, if the deal were already in place and there was a certainty of its effect then the statement might read:

> The company says that **the deal will** allow work to start immediately.

Comment: Also "it would **then** be too late" - **then** means 'if something previously specified were to happen'.